# Google Play Beta Test

Tags: testing, google-play, publish

I'm new with publish on Google Play.
When I have a public app with version 1.0 and now I will test a new apk (same app) with version 1.1.
Can I load the new apk as beta test and there are no conflicts with the public version 1.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Both Production and Beta versions in Google Play](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008657/both-production-and-beta-versions-in-google-play)

Answer (score 0):

Applications that are uploaded to either the alpha testing or beta testing enviroments are completely seperate to the version in production. Also apps in alpha and beta do not appear in the Play Store, testers have to be invited to download the app via Google+.