# Both Production and Beta versions in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, publish, beta

I have published an app in Google Play in Production mode. Now, I have a new version which I want to be release in Beta mode for my limited number of private beta users. Is it possible to have them both? i.e. version 1.0 in production mode and version 1.1 in beta mode? Or should I maintain a different app for beta (which is not convenient, as I need to change package names).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have both, technically you can have 4 apks available to users and depending on other requirements can have even more than that.

Alpha - alpha testers who opt in can test it

Beta  - beta testers who opt in can test, can be different from alpha

Staged Rollout - percentage of users can download

Production - all users, or latest version

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: OP is asking about having Production apk and another one (Alpha or Beta) in **same device**

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have them both?

Yes. It is possible to have them both.

However,

> i.e. version 1.0 in production mode and version 1.1 in beta mode?

It prioritizes the larger version code. So if your version code in Production is 1.0 and 1.1 in Beta, what you will see in Play Store is the one in Beta. Regardless whether it is **Open Beta Testing** or **Communities**. Haven't tried the **Closed Beta Testing**

> Or should I maintain a different app for beta (which is not
>   convenient, as I need to change package names)

In my case, I already have an app in Production until I decided to add in-app products, so I uploaded the in-app version in Beta. It turns out that it has the same package name appearing in Play Store. What I did was to deactivate first the product and disable Beta. When the app is ready, then upload it to Production and have the product activated.

As an additional thought on `versionCode`, let me share this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19943844/2458892)

Comment: So you upload beta with having higher version and disable it immediately without deactivating  it. how do you do that? what google is doing not logical. why should they prioritize if there is an option on beta push to production. Does google show that beta with a beta tag on google playstore?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have both. Google play do not restrict